# html links are not working? Tried various file paths

Tags: html

Wondering if someone can tell me why my links are not working. I have tried directly using the  file path but still no luck.

Im not sure whether it is the css or the html link.  Code snippets below.

### HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="cooking.html" accesskey="1" title="Homepage">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="cookeryclasses.html" accesskey="2" title="Classes">Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="cookeryaboutus.html" accesskey="3" title="About">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.abbeywoodprojects.co.uk/contact.html" accesskey="4" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    width: 600px;
    height: 99px;
}

#menu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 70px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3em;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.10em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #B6B6B6;
}

#menu .active a
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thankyou in advanced

Added a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jSgPR/

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you Fiddle it?

Comment: tell where these files are stored and no need to give CSS as it is only for styling purpose

Comment: Retagged this has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: Does the 'contact' link work? Or is all of them broken?

Comment: All of the links are working (are clickable) in the fiddle for me.

Comment: Try the url http://www.abbeywoodprojects.co.uk/cooking.html .... I dont know my they are not working for me, Have cleared cache etc...

Comment: This bit of CSS `#banner:before` is appearing over the top of the navigation items, which makes them not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links work fine, but the `:before` element is appearing on top of the links.

This bit of CSS is appearing over the top of the `menu`, and thus making the links not clickable:

```
#banner:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /*background: url('images/gradient-bg.png') no-repeat right top;*/
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

You can fix this by adding the following to your CSS file

```
position:relative; z-index:10;
```

Add these to `#menu` and you'll be able to hover and click on the navigation links.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have:

- cooking.html
- cookeryclasses.html
- cookeryaboutus.html

in the same Folder as the php file your using if you use only Filenames and no Paths.

Comment: where are you creating these files? just try moving those files into your file system maybe there is a issue with your webserver.

Comment: sorry, dont know why i put php as a tag. All links are broken, not even the external url is working.

Comment: If even the external link is broken this might be more complicated than first assessed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. Everything will work. `http://jsfiddle.net/jSgPR/1/`

```
<a href="absoluteurl"></a>
```

Comment: Ok, il give it ago. Thanks

Comment: Still no luck, re uploaded with relative paths to the file names. Still not getting any success. ahg!

Comment: your banner is comming in way